# sklearn stratified k-fold CV with linear model like ElasticNetCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

using cross validation (CV) with `sklearn` is quite easy and straight-forward. But the default implementation when setting `cv=5` in a linear CV model, like `ElasticNetCV` or `LassoCV` is a `KFold` CV. For various reasons I'd like to use a `StratifiedKFold`. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV.html), it seems like **any** CV method can be given with `cv=`.

Passing `cv=KFold(5)` works as expected, but `cv=StratifiedKFold(5)` raises the Error:

> ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'continuous' instead.

I know that I can use `cross_val_score` after fitting, but I'd like to pass `StratifiedKFold` as CV directly to the linear model.

My minimum working example is:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNetCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, StratifiedKFold
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100, dtype=np.float64).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.arange(100) + np.random.rand(100)

# KFold default implementation:
model_default = ElasticNetCV(cv=5)
model_default.fit(x, y)  # works fine
# KFold given as cv explicitly:
model_kfexp = ElasticNetCV(cv=KFold(5))
model_kfexp.fit(x, y)  # also works fine

# StratifiedKFold given as cv explicitly:
model_skf = ElasticNetCV(cv=StratifiedKFold(5))
model_skf.fit(x, y)  # THIS RAISES THE ERROR
```

Any idea how I can set `StratifiedKFold` as CV directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of your problem is this line:

```
y = np.arange(100) + np.random.rand(100)
```

`StratifiedKFold` cannot sample from continuous distribution hence your error. Try changing this line and your code will execute happily:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNetCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, StratifiedKFold
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100, dtype=np.float64).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.random.choice([0,1], size=100)

# KFold default implementation:
model_default = ElasticNetCV(cv=5)
model_default.fit(x, y)  # works fine
# KFold given as cv explicitly:
model_kfexp = ElasticNetCV(cv=KFold(5))
model_kfexp.fit(x, y)  # also works fine

# StratifiedKFold given as cv explicitly:
model_skf = ElasticNetCV(cv=StratifiedKFold(5))
model_skf.fit(x, y)  # no ERROR
```

**NOTE**

If you sample on continuous data, use `KFold`. If your target is categorical you may use both `KFold` and  `StratifiedKFold` whichever suits your needs.

**NOTE 2**

If you insist on ***emulating*** stratified sampling on continuous data, you may wish to apply `pandas.cut` to your data, then do stratified sampling on that data, and finally pass resulting `(train_id, test_id)` generator to `cv` param:

```
x = np.arange(100, dtype=np.float64).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.arange(100) + np.random.rand(100)

y_cat = pd.cut(y, 10, labels=range(10))
skf_gen = StratifiedKFold(5).split(x, y_cat)

model_skf = ElasticNetCV(cv=skf_gen)
model_skf.fit(x, y)  # no ERROR
```

Comment: Thanks for that detailed explanation. So strat. KFold is only applicable for categorical data. Especially the emulation under NOTE 2 was very helpful. Even though I will stay with KFold for now, I guess I'll need it soon. :)